# The Count Property in class Matcher in Groovy

Tags: groovy

My question is regarding the property **count** in the matcher class in groovy. Following is an example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
def p= /[a-z]*/
Matcher m= "abc" =~ p

println m.count
```

As you can see, Groovy actually uses the Matcher class in Java. According to javadoc, Matcher doesn't have any count property. We have to use loops to count manually in Java development for pattern matching. How can groovy do this? Is it documented somewhere?

Thanks,

Comment: The `Matcher` class in the Groovy JDK javadoc includes `count`: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: hi, according to the answer, there are differences between java jdk and groovy jdk. In groovy jdk, more features have been implemented. Hence, this is the right solution. Can you please explain why I got down voted for this question? Thanks,

Comment: I didn't vote your question down; I'm assuming someone else may have thought this was "too elementary" for SO. I don't know anything about groovy and it took me about three minutes to find the answer with google.

Answer (score 0):

A good start for this is [Groovy Backstage](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Backstage) and especially [Groovy Method Invocation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Method+Invokation).  Basically the classes get a metaClass augmented with a common set of tools (e.g. `DefaultGroovyMethods` (see below) for `Object`).  On method invocation, groovy takes this into account for "what is there". `count` for `Matcher` is already some more special case, something much more common used on `Object` is e.g. `println`.

If you are interested only in the functionality itself you can check the [GDK](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/). E.g. for [`Matcher.getCount()`](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#getCount%28%29).

If you are interested how it is actually implemented, then a good start is always [`DefaultGroovyMethods`](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html) or the descendants of [`DefaultGroovyMethodsSupport`](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethodsSupport.html) in general.  So following this for `Matcher.getCount()` leeds to https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.java#L1508.